# last-child logic for columns in Bourbon Neat

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

I'm wondering how the 0 margin on the last child is supposed to come in.

I've got:

```
    body {

  @include outer-container;

.content-main.with-sidebar { @include span-columns(8);}

aside { @include span-columns(4); }
    }
```

Body is centered with a max max width -- both .content-main and aside are getting the correct widths,  but neither are getting the `:last-child { margin-right: 0;}` that they're supposed to.  There's other stuff in body, but it's the only parent they've got.

Clearly I'm not doing something right -- but the fact that they're getting widths at all seems like it would indicate that everything is @importing correctly.

With thanks --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at your HTML I can only guess that those aren't actually the last-child. For cases like this there is the `omega()` mixin to use. Look here for the documentation: http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/#omega

Comment: they'd have to be the last child of the parent then -- not just the last element to get @include columns-ed?

Comment: Correct, its the last-child of the parent. Has nothing to do with which have Neat mixins/functions.